# Hide Text Axis and Have Chart Readjust in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have the following table in excel:

```
      A          B           C 
1   Object 1    100         100
2   Object 2     0           0
3   Object 3    100         100
4   Object 4     0           0
```

When I create a stacked bar chart with this values I get the following result:
[image]

[Stacked Bar Chart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNs37.png)

I need to figure out a way for the chart to adjust automatically and exclude any object for which both columns B and C have 0 values. In this case Object 2 and 4. Numbers will flow automatically into my template and I will not be able to manually update the charts. The end result with my example should look like this:

[image]

[Stacked Bar Chart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLYb6.png)

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Just hide the rows with zero values... you can write VBA to do that automatically if needed.

Comment: To clarify a bit more, I will not be able to manipulate the template once the numbers flow in. For the VBA, would it require me to run it manually?

Comment: No, if you use a `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: Thank you, will try that solution and post an update.